# Save bitmap from camera and perform facecrop and biometric stats

Tags: java, android, bitmap, camera, bitmapfactory

So I'm working on a project where I take in an image from either gallery or camera and get a series of statistics from the image (brightness, contrast, sharpness, etc). Currently I have this working from gallery. I can open gallery, pull an image, and if a face is detected it will be cropped in a 2nd imageview. The stats are gathered from the cropped image ( see showimage(bitmap) in the gallery button area ). I've been struggling for the last week trying to get the same thing to work from the camera.

I'm currently using the following open source projects for getting the image from gallery and for cropping the face from the image:

https://github.com/hanscappelle/SO-2169649

https://github.com/lafosca/AndroidFaceCropper

I've made some advancements, and then backtracked a lot because I think I was trying to do it wrong. Here is my current working code for JUST gallery:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// this is the action code we use in our intent,
// this way we know we're looking at the response from our own action
private static final int SELECT_SINGLE_PICTURE = 101;

public static final String IMAGE_TYPE = "image/*";

/* Get the reference to the text label */
TextView label = null;


private ImageView selectedImagePreview;
private ImageView imageViewFace;


void showImage(Bitmap image)
{

    /* Get the starting time */
    long startTime = 0;

    startTime = System.nanoTime();

    /* Get the image statistics */
    ImageStats imageStats = new ImageStats(image);

    System.out.println("Execution time: " + (((double)(System.nanoTime() - startTime))/1000000000.0) + " seconds!");

     /* Get the image statistics */
    double[] stats = imageStats.getStats();

    /*  Decide whether or not the image is of good quality */
    String results = imageStats.result;

     /* Create the labels */
    String[] labels = new String[]{"Standard Luminosity: ", "Contrast: ", "Face orientation: ", "Sharpness: "};

     /* The string of statistics */
    StringBuffer strStatsBuff = new StringBuffer();

     /* Go through all the statistics */
    for(int statIndex = 0; statIndex < stats.length; ++statIndex)
    {
          /* Add the statistics */
        strStatsBuff.append(labels[statIndex]);
        strStatsBuff.append(String.valueOf(stats[statIndex]));
        strStatsBuff.append("\n");
    }

     /* Add the file name */
    strStatsBuff.append("\n");
    strStatsBuff.append(results);

      /* Set the label and show the cropped image */
    label.setText(strStatsBuff.toString());
    FaceCropper mFaceCropper = new FaceCropper();
    mFaceCropper.setEyeDistanceFactorMargin(0);
    image = mFaceCropper.getCroppedImage(image);
    imageViewFace.setImageBitmap(image);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // no need to cast to button view here since we can add a listener to any view, this
    // is the single image selection
    label = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label);

    findViewById(R.id.buttonGallery).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // in onCreate or any event where your want the user to
            // select a file
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType(IMAGE_TYPE);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                    "Select image"), SELECT_SINGLE_PICTURE);
        }
    });

    selectedImagePreview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageViewFace = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewFace);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_SINGLE_PICTURE) {

            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

            try {
                Bitmap bitmap;
                selectedImagePreview.setImageBitmap(new UserPicture(selectedImageUri, getContentResolver()).getBitmap());
                bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImageUri));
                showImage(bitmap);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Failed to load image", e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    } else {
        // report failure
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"failed to get intent data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Failed to get intent data, result code is " + resultCode);
    }
}

}
```

My "closest to working" method pulled an image from the camera, but both the original imageview and the imageview that should have been cropped to face both just showed the original image.

I had the following included under oncreate -

```
        findViewById(R.id.buttonCamera).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View arg0 ){
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });
```

and this included in onactivityresult -

```
 else if (requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            selectedImagePreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
           showImage(bitmap);

        }
```

Welcome to any suggestions! If you need any more info or I haven't provided something obvious, let me know. I'm new to stackoverflow, java, and android. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution now. If anyone needs to do the same or similar here's what mine looks like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// this is the action code we use in our intent,
// this way we know we're looking at the response from our own action
private static final int SELECT_SINGLE_PICTURE = 101;

private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 102;

public static final String IMAGE_TYPE = "image/*";

private final int RequestCode = 20;

Uri mImageCaptureUri1;

/* Get the reference to the text label */
TextView label = null;

ImageView selectedImagePreview;
ImageView imageViewFace;



void showImage(Bitmap image)
{
    imageViewFace.setImageBitmap(null);
    FaceCropper mFaceCropper = new FaceCropper();
    mFaceCropper.setMaxFaces(1);
    mFaceCropper.setEyeDistanceFactorMargin(0);
    image = mFaceCropper.getCroppedImage(image);

    String faceFound;
    if (mFaceCropper.faceDetected==true){
        faceFound = "Face Detected!";
    }else faceFound ="No face detected!";

    /* Get the starting time */
    long startTime = 0;

    startTime = System.nanoTime();

    /* Get the image statistics */
    ImageStats imageStats = new ImageStats(image);

    System.out.println("Execution time: " + (((double)(System.nanoTime() - startTime))/1000000000.0) + " seconds!");

     /* Get the image statistics */
    double[] stats = imageStats.getStats();

    /*  Decide whether or not the image is of good quality */
    String results = imageStats.result;


     /* Create the labels */
    String[] labels = new String[]{"Standard Luminosity: ", "Contrast: ", "Face orientation: ", "Sharpness: "};

     /* The string of statistics */
    StringBuffer strStatsBuff = new StringBuffer();

     /* Go through all the statistics */
    for(int statIndex = 0; statIndex < stats.length; ++statIndex)
    {
          /* Add the statistics */
        strStatsBuff.append(labels[statIndex]);
        strStatsBuff.append(String.valueOf(stats[statIndex]));
        strStatsBuff.append("\n");
    }

     /* Add the file name */
   strStatsBuff.append(faceFound);


      /* Set the label and show the cropped image */
    label.setText(strStatsBuff.toString());


    if (mFaceCropper.faceDetected == true)
    {
        imageViewFace.setImageBitmap(image);

    }

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // no need to cast to button view here since we can add a listener to any view, this
    // is the single image selection
    label = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label);



    findViewById(R.id.buttonGallery).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // in onCreate or any event where your want the user to
            // select a file
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType(IMAGE_TYPE);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                    "Select image"), SELECT_SINGLE_PICTURE);
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.buttonCamera).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View arg0 ){
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            mImageCaptureUri1 = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "tmp_avatar_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));

            cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri1);
            cameraIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });

    selectedImagePreview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageViewFace = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewFace);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_SINGLE_PICTURE) {

            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

            try {
                Bitmap bitmap;
                selectedImagePreview.setImageBitmap(new UserPicture(selectedImageUri, getContentResolver()).getBitmap());
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImageUri));
                selectedImagePreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                showImage(bitmap);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Failed to load image", e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        else if (requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST){

            try {
                Bitmap bitmap;
                selectedImagePreview.setImageBitmap(new UserPicture(mImageCaptureUri1, getContentResolver()).getBitmap());
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(mImageCaptureUri1));
                selectedImagePreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmm").format(new Date());


                showImage(bitmap);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Failed to load image", e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }

    }



    else {
        // report failure
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"failed to get intent data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Failed to get intent data, result code is " + resultCode);
    }
}
}
```